# Bundle Handsontable into Aurelia application

Tags: javascript, bundle, aurelia, handsontable

I'd like to know how to correctly bundle [handsontable](https://handsontable.com%20handsontable) community edition library into Aurelia application. Handsontable is distributed as single JS file packed as webpack module, thus a hint may be useful for webpack modules generally.

Having Aurelia version 0.24.0 configured with default loader: RequireJS and default transpiler: Babel, NPM version 3.10.0. I did following steps in order to bundle handsontable into my application:

```
npm install handsontable
```

then edited aurelia-project/aurelia.json to add the following

```
dependencies:{ ...
  {
    "name": "handsontable",
    "path": "../node_modules/handsontable",
    "main": "dist/handsontable.full",
    "resources": [
      "dist/handsontable.full.css"
     ]
  },
```

Then the component looks like: (view - htable.html):

```
<template>
<div ref="filetable"></div>
</template>
```

(viewmodel - htable.js in ES6):

```
import {Handsontable} from "handsontable";

export class htable {
...
   attached() {
     this.ht = new Handsontable (this.filetable, {
       data: this.data,
       rowHeaders: true,
       colHeaders: true
      });
   }
 }
```

However, any attempt to add such component fails with

```
Unhandled rejection TypeError: _handsontable is undefined
```

Another attemp I use in different library produce similar error:

```
import * as Handsontable from "handsontable";
...
     this.ht = new Handsontable.Handsontable (this.filetable, {
```

Btw. A workaround is not to bundle and add handsontable into index.html which makes "Handsontable" global.

Comment: Please provide info on how your aurelia project is configured with cli. which loader? require, systemjs or webpack bundling?

Comment: @AlexanderTaran Aurelia project is configured with default loader: RequireJS and default transpiler: Babel

Comment: Played with it a bit with no success.
I remember when we tried to integrate it before it was hard.
The way they package it is not that module friendly.
Ended up using global